# Excel: Using a formula to search a column and replace cells

Tags: excel

Sorry this may seems super basic but im struggling with excel at the moment as I am self teaching. I'm looking for a function which will search a column and replace all instances of "Big" with 1 and "Tiny" with a 0.

Comment: Have you done a 'Find` and `Replace` before?

Comment: I have done very basic formulas yes but retrofitting a column instead of creating a new one seems tough.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to simply go to `Find & Select` --> `Replace` from the `Home` tab (assumes excel 2010). You can then replace 'Big' with 1 there, etc.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it with a formula instead of inbuilt functionality, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in column B, then in column A you could have something like

```
=if(B1="Big",1,if(B1="Tiny",0,B1))
```

Then copy that formula down your column to make a new column with the replacements you want made.

If you don't want to create a new column, but just modify the old one, then you could use vba, like so

```
Sub myReplace()
for i = 1 to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  if cells(i,1) = "Big" then
    cells(i,1) = 1
  elseif cells(i,1) = "Tiny" then
    cells(i,1) = 0
  end if
next i
end sub
```

This assumes your column of interest is column A.

Comment: Okay yes that is great, so that will read a whole column and replace it? and what is the variable for changing which column it tests for instead say like column K?

Comment: The `1` in `cells(i,1)` refers to the first column, or column A. For, say, column K, you need to replace the `1` with an `11` in each of those instances.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the column, hit `CTRL+H` to bring up the search and replace box, tell it what you want to do.

If you prefer a formulaic way and the words are within a text string, `=SUBSTITUTE(text,old_text,new_text,[nth_appearance])` would do the job as well.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I suggested, but asker is insisting on something custom-made.

Comment: Yeah, would seem you were tyyping your answer as I was typing mine. Not very clear in the question what asker's data is like.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the `Find and Replace` option that you mention, but the asker seems to neither want that nor involving the additional column that `=SUBSTITUTE(...)` would require.